# How to normalize password before hashing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, unicode-normalization

I am using the Node.js library in my asp.net application to normalize the password string by using its UNorm.normalize function like this UNorm.normalize("NFC",strpwd); but it does not give me any output. To trace it I execute it in debug mode and I found that error occurs in unorm.js file function fromData(next, cp, needFeature) and it says that " javascript runtime error unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference". If I presses the ignore button then it shows me the output but if I click continue or break button then no output produces. I get the Node.js library code from  http://git.io/unorm. My application code is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="unorm-master/src/unorm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 function strNormalize()
 {  

    var nstr;
    var strpwd = 'αλφα';

    nstr = UNorm.normalize('NFC',strpwd);    

    document.getElementById("txtNormalize").value = nstr;  

 }
 </script>
```

Can anyone tell me that how to fix this issue in Node.js file unorm.js? Or propose any other solution using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

convert to punycode via https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/ and then hash

as long as you do the same convert both ways (e.g. when you do the first hash to store and when you do the hash for verification) you should be good.

e.g. the punycode for your example would be "--mxaa3a7b"

Comment: it's another way of doing what you're doing.  instead of getting the unicode, you just do punycode (which is ascii) which is good enough for the problems you are encountering. all you're trying to do is save a password, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using this library incorrectly, there are some examples in readme, try:

```
nstr = UNorm.nfc(strpwd);
```

Comment: I tried it also but same error occurs with this also. Can you please tell me how to use this library I just include the script files available at http://git.io/unorm with the same structure and use them by including its path. I only include unorm.js file If i tried to include unormdata.js file as well then Unorm is not available. Can you please tell me how to use this library correctly?

Comment: Then I guess this is error in unorm library, try contacting library developer for a fix

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you are targeting you could just use `String.prototype.normalize()` ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)). To quote the documentation:

> The normalize() method returns the Unicode Normalization Form of a
>   given string (if the value isn't a string, it will be converted to one
>   first).
>
> **Parameters**
>
> form One of `NFC`, `NFD`, `NFKC`, or `NFKD`, specifying the Unicode
>   Normalization Form. If omitted or undefined, `NFC` is used.
>
> - `NFC` — Normalization Form Canonical Composition.
> - `NFD` — Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition.
> - `NFKC` — Normalization Form Compatibility Composition.
> - `NFKD` — Normalization Form Compatibility Decomposition.

As an example `"\u1E9B\u0323".normalize()` will produce a string using NFC form.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2022, the currently relevant authority from IETF is [RFC 8265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8265), “Preparation, Enforcement, and Comparison of Internationalized Strings Representing Usernames and Passwords,” October 2017. This document about usernames and passwords is a special case of the more-general PRECIS specification in the still-authoritative [RFC 8264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8264), “PRECIS Framework: Preparation, Enforcement, and Comparison of Internationalized Strings in Application Protocols,” October 2017.

RFC 8265, [§ 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8265#section-4.1):

> This document specifies that a password is a string of Unicode code points [Unicode] that is conformant to the OpaqueString profile (specified below) of the PRECIS FreeformClass defined in Section 4.3 of [RFC8264] and expressed in a standard Unicode Encoding Form (such as UTF-8 [RFC3629]).

RFC 8265, [§ 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8265#section-4.2) defines the `OpaqueString` profile, the enforcement of which requires that the following rules be applied in the following order:

- the string must be prepared to ensure that it consists only of Unicode code point explicitly allowed by the `FreeformClass` string class defined in [RFC 8264, § 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8264#section-4.3). Certain characters are specified as:

  - Valid: traditional letters and number, all printable, non-space code points from the 7-bit ASCII range, space code points, symbol code points, punctuation code points, “[a]ny code point that is decomposed and recomposed into something other than itself under Unicode Normalization Form KC, i.e., the HasCompat (‘Q’) category defined under Section 9.17,” and “[l]etters and digits other than the ‘traditional’ letters and digits allowed in IDNs, i.e., the OtherLetterDigits (‘R’) category defined under Section 9.18.”
  - Invalid: Old Hangul Jamo code points, control code points, and ignorable code points. Further, any currently unassigned code points are considered invalid.
  - “Contextual Rule Required”: a number of code points from an “
    Exceptions” category and “joining code points.” (“Contextual Rule Required” [means](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8264#section-8): “Some characteristics of the code point, such as its being invisible in certain contexts or problematic in others, require that it not be used in a string unless specific other code points or properties are present in the string.”)
- Width Mapping Rule: Fullwidth and halfwidth code points MUST NOT be mapped to their decomposition mappings.
- Additional Mapping Rule: Any instances of non-ASCII space MUST be mapped to SPACE (U+0020).
- Unicode Normalization Form C (NFC) MUST be applied to all strings.

There is a JavaScript implementation of PRECIS, e.g., [PRECIS-JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/precis-js), though I haven’t used it and therefore can’t vouch for it. Its documentation gives this simple implementation example:

```
precis = require('precis-js');
profile = new precis.profile.UsernameCaseMappedProfile();
 
try {
    result = precis.enforce(profile, string);
} catch (e) {
    // handle error
}
```

I found Paweł Krawczyk’s “[PRECIS, the next step in Unicode validation](https://krvtz.net/posts/precis-the-next-step-in-unicode-validation.html)” a very helpful introduction.